# How to get the difference between the two entries of the same day?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"datetime": ["30.12.1999 00:59:00", "30.12.1999 23:59:00", "31.12.1999 00:59:00", "31.12.1999 23:59:00"], "b": [4, 15, 26,7]})
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df.datetime)
df["date"]=df.datetime.dt.date
```

which looks like:

```
             datetime   b        date
0 1999-12-30 00:59:00   4  1999-12-30
1 1999-12-30 23:59:00  15  1999-12-30
2 1999-12-31 00:59:00  26  1999-12-31
3 1999-12-31 23:59:00   7  1999-12-31
```

The dataframe has much more rows in reality, but the following principle is still valid: you have just two rows for one day.

I would like to get the difference between the two values for `b`. So in the example above, I would like to have a resulting dataframe that looks like:

```
        date  b_delta
0 1999-12-30       11
1 1999-12-31      -19
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way to do this would be:

```
df.set_index('date').groupby('date')['b'].diff().reset_index(name='b_delta').dropna()
```

The output:

```
date           b_delta
1999-12-30     11.0
1999-12-31    -19.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would set the index to `date`, groupby that, and use `diff` on column `b` to subtract consecutive values. Then, you can select just the non-null values:

```
g = df.set_index('date').groupby(level=0).b.diff()
g[g.notnull()]

date
1999-12-30    11.0
1999-12-31   -19.0
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

You can set it to a dataframe with your desired `b_delta` header like so:

```
>>> g[g.notnull()].to_frame('b_delta')
            b_delta
date               
1999-12-30     11.0
1999-12-31    -19.0
```

**Edit**: I overlooked using `dropna`, which is really the way to go here (as in @AbhinavSood's great answer, which honestly should be the accepted answer...):

```
df.set_index('date').groupby(level=0).b.diff().dropna().to_frame('b_delta')
```